# Parse binary string as byte in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript

I have a binary string like `"11100011"` and I want to convert it into a byte. I have a working example in *Java* like below:

```
byte b1 = (byte)Integer.parseInt("11100011", 2);
System.out.println(b1);
```

Here the output will be `-29`. But if I write some similar code in JavaScript like below:

```
parseInt('11100011', 2);
```

I get an output of `227`.

What JavaScript code I should write to get the same output as Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java is interpreting the `byte` as being a signed two's-complement number, which is negative since the highest bit is 1. Javascript is interpreting it as unsigned, so it's always positive.

Try this:

```
var b1 = parseInt('11100011', 2);
if(b1 > 127) b1 -= 256;
```