# Using Javascript, how do I convert a binary string (1s and 0s) back into a Unicode character?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, binary

I'm new here. Using Javascript, I have successfully converted a Unicode character into a binary string (i.e., into 1s and 0s). Now, how would I convert that string back into the original Unicode character (UTF-8 I think). I have found a few code examples--but unfortunately the conversions do not work in converting the binary string back into the original character.

Here's the binary string (which is a "thumbs up" emoji):

```
11110000100111111001000110001101
```

Thanks, and any code examples you could prove (in pure Javascript) would be most welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Basic Google-fu:

1. [Split large string in n-size chunks in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29202760/3439404)
2. [Parse binary string as byte in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26430848/3439404)
3. [Conversion between UTF-8 ArrayBuffer and String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17192845/3439404)

Putting above together (sorry for my poor JS skills):

```js
function chunkSubstr(str, size) {
  const numChunks = Math.ceil(str.length / size)
  const chunks = new Array(numChunks)

  for (let i = 0, o = 0; i < numChunks; ++i, o += size) {
    chunks[i] = parseInt(str.substr(o, size),2)
  }

  return chunks
}
function uintToString(uintArray) {
    var encodedString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uintArray),
        decodedString = decodeURIComponent(escape(encodedString));
    return decodedString;
}

console.log(uintToString(chunkSubstr("11110000100111111001000110001101", 8))); //
```

Comment: Great answer; much appreciated. 

FYI: Code to initially convert a string to binary can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55955730/how-to-convert-a-string-into-its-real-binary-representation-utf-8-or-whatever

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.